# Add all folder in subfolder of assets in pubspec.yaml at once?

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

I have some folder in `assets/images` such as :

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/home/
    - assets/images/shop/
    - assets/images/profile/
    - assets/images/etc/
```

is there any way to add all subfolder at once? seems like `assets/images/*` or something?
many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Only files located directly in the directory are included unless there are files with the same name inside a subdirectory (see [Asset Variants](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html)). To add files located in subdirectories, create an entry per directory.
[see more](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets)